# SAP UI5 application does not start

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, sap-fiori

​Hello Everyone,

A SAP UI5 application does not start from the Fiori Launchpad.

[image]

I looked at the developer tools as well and i have several errors .
[image]

The services are active in SICF.

In the manifest.json the Id is correct
[image]

These are the things that i have found that could cause the problem but now i am stuck what could be the issue.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The issue is in the last line of the error. With your current setup, it cannot find `Component.js` in the location specified, which seems to be under the `ushell` resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I don't actually now what the problem was but i put everyting into the WebContent subfolder as was the case with other UI5 applications and that resolved the problem. The application did not work after Eclipse added some files, so its possible it added something that referred to WebContent folder path.